# Breadcrumbs <Link> wrapped in <li> not clickable nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using this [blog](https://blog.anishde.dev/making-an-accessible-breadcrumb-navigation-using-tailwindcss-and-nextjs#comments-list) as a reference as I implement breadcrumbs for a nextjs app. Everything works well except the breadcrumbs are not clickable. I would like the user to be able to click on a breadcrumb and be redirected to its path.
My assumption is that wrapping the link in li tags is what brings this issue but am not sure why. Will appreciate a third eye

**components/BreadrumbItem.jsx**

```
import Link from "next/link";

const BreadcrumbItem = ({ children, href, ...props }) => {

  return (
    <li {...props}>
      <Link href={href} passHref>
        <a>
          {children}
        </a>
      </Link>
    </li>
  );
};

export default BreadcrumbItem;
```

**components/Breadcrumb.jsx**

```
import { Children } from "react";
import { Fragment } from "react";

const Breadcrumb = ({ children }) => {
  const childrenArray = Children.toArray(children);

  const childrenWtihSeperator = childrenArray.map((child, index) => {
    if (index !== childrenArray.length - 1) {
      return (
        <Fragment key={index}>
          {child}
          <span className="text-gray-400 text-[16px] font-medium">{">"}</span>
        </Fragment>
      );
    }
    return child;
  });

  return (
    <nav className="mx-8 md:mx-16 lg:mx-0 -mt-9 mb-2" aria-label="breadcrumb">
      <ol className="flex items-center space-x-1">{childrenWtihSeperator}</ol>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Breadcrumb;
```

**components/layout.tsx**

```
const Layout = ({ children }: Props) => {

  const router = useRouter();
  
  const [breadcrumbs, setBreadcrumbs] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const pathWithoutQuery = router.asPath.split("?")[0];
    let pathArray = pathWithoutQuery.split("/");
    pathArray.shift();

    pathArray = pathArray.filter((path) => path !== "");

    const breadcrumbs = pathArray.map((path, index) => {
      const href = "/" + pathArray.slice(0, index + 1).join("/");
      return {
        href,
        label: path.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + path.slice(1),
        isCurrent: index === pathArray.length - 1,
      };
    });
//@ts-ignore
    setBreadcrumbs(breadcrumbs); 
  }, [router.asPath]);
  
  return (
    <>
     <Breadcrumb>
        <BreadcrumbItem isCurrent={router.pathname === "/"} href="/">
          Home
        </BreadcrumbItem>
        {breadcrumbs &&
        //@ts-ignore
          breadcrumbs.map((breadcrumb) => (
            <BreadcrumbItem
              key={breadcrumb.href}
              href={breadcrumb.href}
              isCurrent={breadcrumb.isCurrent}
            >
              {breadcrumb.label}
            </BreadcrumbItem>
          ))}
      </Breadcrumb>
    </>
  )
}

export default Layout;
```

Comment: You shouldn't use an `<a>` inside a `<Link>`. You can just use `<Link href={href}>{children}</Link>`

Comment: @koolskateguy89 the result is the same. I think the issue is in what wraps the link rather than what is wrapped in it